# Where can I ask about a problem I'm having with Instagram?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm not sure which community I should ask this question to. I have a very specific problem with logging into Instagram, and using Google I didn't find any posts where anyone has the exact same problem; all have a longer error message or more options.

This would be the question:

> I try logging into one of my Instagram accounts, the other one works just fine without any problems. On the desktop page I get:
>
> > Confirm Your Info on the App
> >
> > Confirm your information using the Instagram app to try to get back to your account.
>
> and nothing else. Nothing about any weird activities or my account being suspended or anything, the account still exists: https://www.instagram.com/haku_blue_bayou/. When I try to log in on my app, I get "couldn't refresh feed", then "loading" and then the screen turns black and stays like this (it's white if I disable the dark theme).
>
> I tried: restarting my phone, deleting app cache and storage, uninstalling and reinstalling the app, uninstalling and reinstalling an older version of the app, trying it out on different devices (Sony Xperia XZ2, Google Nexus7), resetting my password through email and facebook-account, changing app permissions so Instagram has access to my camera and storage.

Answer (score 10):

Instagram is a web application so you could try asking on the [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) site. It does have an [instagram](/questions/tagged/instagram) tag.

> A free photo sharing application that allows users to take photos, apply a filter, and share it on the service or a variety of other social networking services.

that has [more than 150 questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instagram) already. Do check those questions and the [Web Applications help centre](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help) to see if your question would fit.